# Solving the memory leak issues

Tags: wpf, debugging, c#-4.0, memory-leaks

I have read a lot about this topic, and still I don't have the clear path how to proceed. Can anyone point to some resource (or explain) that shows in detailed step how to find the reason why some objects dctor is not called.

basically my logic for testing leak is this (WPF application):

1. create some View/ViewModel
2. close the View
3. call GC.Collect()

After a few seconds a dctor on ViewModel class is normally called, but on my application is never called. I would like to know which object is holding a reference to it at that time, since in my opinion it is the way to find the cause of memory leak.

This classes do not user any unmanaged resources, and do not have `IDisposable` implemented, which means there is no SupressFinalize call to prevent desctructor execution.

Edit: ViewModel is retrieved through a Static property on ViewModelLocator, and is added List. This is required by TabControl, which needs collection of view models to bind to. View and ViewModel are connected through DataTemplate.

Comment: This question is hard to answer without knowing how you're using your viewModel

Comment: Apologiez, I thought that the method to detecting memory leak is the same for most scenarios. I am adding information about how do I use VM

Comment: On a side note, if your classes are not using unmanaged resources, you really shouldn't implement a finalizer for them; the state of the object at the time of finalization is such that you should not assume that you can access any managed references that were previously valid on the class while it was alive.  Finalizers are only intended for unmanaged cleanup (and then really only as a backup to proper deterministic Disposal.)

Comment: Hi Dan, I don't this is just debug info used for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, search for non-unsubscribed event handlers and static references pointing to your ViewModel, even indirectly. Since you're in a WPF application, also ensure that you don't use `DependencyPropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged` which is known to cause leaks by using static references.

If you can't find anything manually, use the awesome (this is my opinion, I'm in no way affiliated with them) [SciTech .NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/). You can see for every object all the references it holds and which other objects are holding a reference to it, in a nice graph 
view. It also warns you for common memory problems.

EDIT:

> ViewModel is retrieved through a Static property on ViewModelLocator

Search no longer, you have your leak. Static references prevent objects from being garbage collected. Remove the static reference or wrap it in a `WeakReference`.

Comment: Hi Julien, I have corrected ViewModelLocator to use singleton pattern, so no more static properties. When we speak of non-unsuscribed event handlers, I used a lot anonymous methods in my app. For example, for each RelayCommand (MVVM light framework) I am using anonymous method, so there is no unsubscribtion. Can that create a memory leak? I ask this because with .NET memory profiler I get lots of reports of type indirect delegate roots and I see that in some entrances ICommands are reported.